why TinyMCE editor is not showing SCRIPT tag?
I receive db data but 'script' part is not showing in editor.
Data comes from database, could come in any form, but none are working.
None of these work:
<code>&lt;script defer src="..."&gt;</code>

<code>&lt;script defer src="..."&gt;... &lt;/script&gt;</code>

<code>< script defer src="..."></code>

<code><script defer src="...">...</script></code>

<script defer src="...">

<script defer src="...">...</script>


INIT:
tinymce.init({
   selector: '#content',
   extended_valid_elements: '*[*]',
. . .

